# Structural equations: how to specify interaction effects in R lavaan package

Tags: r, interaction, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am using [R lavaan package](http://lavaan.ugent.be/) to estimate a structural equation model. Let's say the model consists of 1 endogenous manifest variable with 1 latent and 2 manifest explanatory variables:

```
group = {0,1}
attitude1 = latent,scale
age = respondent's age
```

The desired lavaan model is then (doesn't work):

```
model <- '
attitude1 =~ att1 + att2 + att3
outcome ~ age*group + attitude1*group'
```

My goal is, in the lines of what can be done in linear regression, to **establish main and interaction effects between each variable and group. Can this be done?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't currently a method implemented at the model level, but you can create a new variable that is just `attitude1*group`, or you can just use multigroup analysis, which may be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the group invariability analysis gives really weird results (one of the groups is much smaller), while the linear regression makes sense, but SEM is more appropriate due to having scales as independent.

Comment: Yeah, then try calculating an interaction effect variable.

Comment: Note - the latest version of lavaan introduces the `a:b` syntax for observed variables.